# Как уменьшить картинку без артефактов?

Tags: photoshop

Я пытаюсь уменьшить картинку со 100 * 100 пикселей до 60 * 60. Но появляются артефакты - пиксели становятся неровные и цвета меняются чуток. Не могли бы подсказать, как правильно уменьшать картинку?

Comment: Если **вдруг** нет желания заморачиваться с настройками и\или требуется уменьшить в большом кол-ве, то есть различные онлайн инструменты, например этот - [`I❤IMG`](https://www.iloveimg.com/ru/resize-image)

Comment: Странно, никогда такого не было, попробуйте различные вариации сглаживания

Comment: Не забудьте перевести в 24-битную палитру, если у вас 8-битная

Comment: Понимаю, что стоит тег "photoshop", но никогда не рекомендую его использовать для таких вещей - к примеру, бесплатный faststone справляется гораздо лучше